# Jquery internal reference not working

Tags: jquery, master-pages

I was given a stripped down C# web forms project that didn't automatically include the setup for Jquery that a new VS2012 project seems to have.  I tried various ways of registering the internal link for Jquery within the Site.Master page like this below with the ~ and ../ in my reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

then this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMasterPage" runat="server">
<Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />

</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

as well as this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")%>'>  </script>
```

Jquery would not work until I referenced an external link like this below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

So, it's definitely not "seeing" the reference.  The site.master that I'm working with was setup in a subfolder by another person 2 layers down.

Anyone come across this issue before along with a resolution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add ../ before /Scripts ?

You might need to go up one level if your JS file is in another

Comment: Yea, I've tried going one more ../ up the path.  I guess I could just keep adding more and maybe one of them will start to work.  I just find it somewhat bizarre.  Edit:  I just tried tacking on quite a few extra ../ and no luck.

Comment: why don't you use google API for jquery ? and depending on the application I think it is better not to host it.